# Should Rails apps be run by a system user or a regular user?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails

In a production environment on Ubuntu (12.04), should a Rails app be run by a system or a regular user?

I'm creating a dedicated user to running the a rails app and I'm not sure whether to create a regular or a system user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real difference is range of IDs and some default values, I tend to go with "normal" users to not (potentially) collide with other stuff. Just make sure that:

- Login to account is disabled (maybe except ssh with pubkey, but try to avoid that if possible)
- No shell (/bin/false|/bin/nologin) - you can still use 'sudo -u username bash' to log in on it if you need something done from that user